# Is it possible to reference a property using Django's QuerySet.values_list?

Tags: django, properties, django-queryset

I have a custom property on my Django model that returns the full name of a Person:

```
class Person(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def _get_full_name(self):
  return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
full_name = property(_get_full_name)
```

When I create a query, I'd like to reference that property.  For example:

```
people = Person.objects.all().values_list('full_name')
```

Unfortunately, Django yields the following FieldError:

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'full_name' into field

Long story short, is it possible to access a custom property via the values_list() method?  If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how to best remedy this problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

full name is not a field in the django model, it is not possible.
you can use  list comprehensions

```
[person.fullname for person in Person.objects.all() ]
```

Comment: I used this solution to filter the choices for a form field in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417673/django-values-list-multiple-fields-concatenated/11417829#11417829.

Comment: Be careful to performance using this solution. If there are many persons, iterate over all objects could take a while. As an alternative, consider using annotation instead.

Answer (score 21):

`values_list` can only work on fields retrieved directly from the database. As zaca notes, you'll need a list comprehension on the actual queryset:

```
[person.fullname for person in Person.objects.all()]
```

Don't over-use `values_list`. It's just meant as a means of limiting the db query, for when you *know* you'll only ever need those particular fields. For almost all uses, getting the standard queryset is efficient enough.

Comment: This is great. I'm using a is_reporting @property and yeah I reallized I can't use the field in the queryset. too bad it has to iterate through all the objects rather than going for the ones with set to True or False.  Even if you add it to the queryset manager used, it still has to iterate through each anyways to compute the value. Sometimes I guess its worth storing the end result so you can query on it.

Answer (score 10):

Full name is not a field in the Django model, so you can use annotation like:

```
people = Person.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        'first_name', 
        Value(' '), 
        'last_name'
    )
).values_list('full_name')
```