# How do I iterate over or access the @property of a related model in another @property?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to return a sum of fields (with @property) from a related model, that is itself the same type of sum (again using @property).  I'm running into an issue that the Queryset that is being created in the ExpenseCategory model is either not iterable, or that the 'total_amount' is not a field in the related model (which is understandable).  How should I approach this?

```
class ExpenseCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        expenses = self.category_expenses.all()
        return expenses.aggregate(Sum('total_amount'))

class ExpenseLineItem(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(ExpenseCategory, related_name='category_expenses')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0)

    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        return self.amount
```

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to accomplish will work here. Have a read through this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143438/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-property-using-djangos-queryset-values-list

Comment: @WiggyA. Thank you! That did the trick.